# How to decrypt data using RSA with private key in XML format?

Tags: python, xml, rsa, private-key, pycrypto

I have a private key in XML format:

```xml
<RSAKeyValue>
<Modulus>...</Modulus>
<Exponent>...</Exponent>
<P>...</P>
<Q>...</Q>
<DP>...</DP>
<DQ>...</DQ>
<InverseQ>...</InverseQ>
<D>...</D>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

and data (string):

`TTg14X6YfQKJUG0keHzMqp-mvT52J0vkrvP_qwWQvdzzdnLxRXn7i5Aj6AWbO9CWsPw2VO5-fCsJt0pZM_4W2PIk-ThXbJEuOLZbisRI4_...`

is encrypted base64 from public key.

**How do I decrypt this data with private key in XML form like above?**

This works in C#:

```cs
public static byte[] DecryptRSAToByte(string dataDecrypt, string xmlPrivateKey)
{
  RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCryptoServiceProvider =
  newRSACryptoServiceProvider(1024);
  rsaCryptoServiceProvider.FromXmlString(xmlPrivateKey);
  byte[] bytes = SafeBase64Url.DecodeBase64Url(dataDecrypt);
  byte[] decrypted = rsaCryptoServiceProvider.Decrypt(bytes, false);
  return decrypted;
}
```

**How can I do the same thing in Python?**

Comment: Pycryptodome offers a construct method to import a private key by its components . You just need to extract the key data from the XML file

Comment: @MichaelFehr Hi Michael, I don't have any files, I only have 1 private key string in xml form

Comment: Then extract the 8 key components from your XML form (modulus, exponent,  ...) and feed them to the construct function.

Comment: Does not matter if file or string. The built-in xml parser supports parsing of files and strings:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml

Comment: Thanks everyone, I'm resolved issue.

Answer (score 0):

The following codes converts RSA keys in XML to PEM format. Help yourself for encryption and decryption.

```py
import base64

from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def convert_xml_to_pem(private_key_xml_content: str, public_key_xml_content: str):
    # Load private key from XML
    private_key_data = ET.fromstring(private_key_xml_content)
    public_key_data = ET.fromstring(public_key_xml_content)
    inverseQ = int.from_bytes(base64.b64decode(private_key_data.find('InverseQ').text), 'big')
    modulus = int.from_bytes(base64.b64decode(private_key_data.find('Modulus').text), 'big')
    p = int.from_bytes(base64.b64decode(private_key_data.find('P').text), 'big')
    inverseQmodP = inverseQ % p
    exponent = int.from_bytes(base64.b64decode(public_key_data.find('Exponent').text), 'big')
    public_numbers = rsa.RSAPublicNumbers(exponent, modulus)
    private_key = rsa.RSAPrivateNumbers(
        p,
        int.from_bytes(base64.b64decode(private_key_data.find('Q').text), 'big'),
        int.from_bytes(base64.b64decode(private_key_data.find('D').text), 'big'),
        int.from_bytes(base64.b64decode(private_key_data.find('DP').text), 'big'),
        int.from_bytes(base64.b64decode(private_key_data.find('DQ').text), 'big'),
        inverseQmodP,
        public_numbers,
        # int(private_key_data.find('InverseQ').text, 16)
    ).private_key(default_backend())

    private_key_pem = private_key.private_bytes(
            encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
            format=serialization.PrivateFormat.TraditionalOpenSSL,
            encryption_algorithm=serialization.NoEncryption()
        )

    # Load public key from XML
    # public_key_data = ET.fromstring(public_key_xml_content)
    public_key = public_numbers.public_key(default_backend())

    public_key_pem = public_key.public_bytes(
            encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
            format=serialization.PublicFormat.SubjectPublicKeyInfo
        )
    return private_key_pem, public_key_pem


from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
private_key_pem, public_key_pem = convert_xml_to_pem(private_key_xml, public_key_xml)
private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(private_key_pem, password=None)
signature = private_key.sign(
    HASH_OF_YOUR_MESSAGE,  # from hashlib import sha1; sha1(bytes).digest()
    padding.PSS(
        mgf=padding.MGF1(hashes.SHA1()),
        salt_length=padding.PSS.MAX_LENGTH
    ),
    hashes.SHA1()
)
```